# Setting an icon image to top right and bottom left buttons

Tags: java, swing, jframe, grid-layout

How would I go about creating a 4x4 grid of colored,clickable areas using swing?  Ok, so I have the buttons I need. This is the updated code I have.  I am now trying to to get a text field or jlabel to show up on the bottom left.  But I can't get it to work.  I thought making another panel could fix it but apparently not.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Heist {

ArrayList<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();

public Heist(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hesit!");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel top = new JPanel();
    top.setLayout(new BoxLayout(top,BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
    top.add(new JTextField("Moves: "));

    JPanel center = new JPanel();
    center.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        center.add(new JButton());
                    buttons.add(new JButton());
    }

    JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
    JPanel bottomR = new JPanel();
    bottom.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    bottomR.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    bottomR.add(new JButton ("EMP"));
    bottomR.add(new JButton ("Reset"));
    bottom.add(new JTextField("Enter/Exit"));

    Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
    pane.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    pane.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pane.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pane.add(bottomR, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Heist gui = new Heist();
}
```

}

Comment: Brevity is the soul of wit they say, but we're stretching things

Comment: Sorry, but to be blunt, yours is a lazy question. In the future (or **now** even), you'll get better help if you show your attempt to solve it first. If you don't do this, how will we know where you're stuck or what confuses you? Also your showing your effort gains much in terms of respect for you and your question, showing that you're willing to put in the effort and initiative to try to solve it yourself first.

Comment: Alright, well so far I have made the intital gui, but I'm not sure how to add the areas.  I have tried adding multiple buttons but it only shows one button. So how about I ask, how can I fix this issue first?

Comment: The [essentials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html), the [easy way](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), the [hard way](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Comment: If you have made the gui, you would be better off posting what you have and ask about the problems you face when trying to implement buttons.

Comment: Ok, I'll check those links and get back on here with some more code then.

Comment: @MadProgrammer's answer has some great links that you should follow. 1+

Comment: You're not adding any JButtons to your GUI. Please show your code attempt for that too.

Answer (score 2):

> Alright, well so far I have made the intital gui, but I'm not sure how
>   to add the areas. I have tried adding multiple buttons but it only
>   shows one button

The default layout manager for a `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`, which will only allow a single component to occupy any of the five available positions it supports.  The default position been the  `CENTER` position

Try using a [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) instead

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: Alright so I had that when I started. But it never worked out for me.  I think I might have been adding buttons wrong. But then one button did always show up.